# How to programly set the detail status for lock-screen using C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, lockscreen

I am new to WP 8.1 development, but I know C# quite well. 
I am developing a APP to display some personalized text on the lock screen, there is such app in the APP Store already, but I am want to use my own APP.  The only thing is that I do not know how to change detailed status of an APP which will be displayed on lock screen. I already able to make my app be the one that will display detailed status. But I do not know what APIs to use. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there's no way to programmatically do this. The best you can do is from your app, bring the user to 'Lock Screen, Phone Settings' and from there, the user has to select 'Your App' as the app to show 'Detailed Status'.  Then, what will be shown on the Lock Screen will be the first three lines of text from the Wide Live Tile, so you'll need to set that up. Note that if you have your Live Tile set up to cycle through multiple (up to and including five) notifications, the freshest notification will be shown on the Lock Screen.